# In Android (Java) can you pass a photo using LiveData and a shared ViewModel between two fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'd like to know if in Android (Java) you can pass a photo using LiveData and a shared ViewModel between two fragments? I have hunted high and low online and can only find references online to something similar in Kotlin. Please excuse the basic question I'm a complete beginner. I have implemented working camera functionality within a fragment, but I would now like to display the resulting image in another fragment.

If this is possible, would I need to put the reference to the ViewModel in the onActivityResult() method in my existing fragment?

I am working with a bitmap so will I need to use Glide?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: nearly any reference you find to kotlin code has a java equivalent

Comment: Thank you, yes, but sadly my Kotlin is not good enough yet to translate Kotlin examples into Java.

Comment: Glide is not necessary

Comment: Now Android restricts sending bitmaps trough intents, so you need to save the image in the camera fragment and send the path as a string to the next one

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, if you have found a **Kotlin** example you want to use, you can decompile the bytecode to view it in **Java**.

If you are using **Android Studio** or **IntelliJ IDEA**,

1. Open the Kotlin file
2. From the main menu select **Tools** -> **Kotlin** -> **Show Kotlin Bytecode**
3. Click **Decompile**

[This is what the option menu should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQhZy.png)

**Kotlin** and **Java** are interoperable because they both use the Java Virtual Machine. So they are compiled to the same bytecode.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use **`LiveData`** in java to expose any entity as a **`Observable Viewholder`**, which in your case is a photo. I assume you would like to change the bitmap as a reasoning to keeping it a **`livedata`**. Sharing the instance between two different **`Lifecycle owners`**, in your case are **`Fragments`** is possible by keeping the **`livedata`** instance in a share **`ViewModel`**. Both these **`lifecycler owners`** can observe this single **`viewModel`**.

You do not need to put reference in onActivityResult() rather make the two fragments get a reference to the shared viewModel through **`ViewModelProviders`**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I don't think I need to change the bitmap. Is there a different way to do this with a ViewModel but not using LiveData?  I'm happy to get the photo to the other fragment in anyway possible that is efficient because at the moment I don't know how to and I don't know what the best way to do this would be. I am very grateful for suggestions.

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272914/sharing-data-between-fragments-using-new-architecture-component-viewmodel

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at that.