# Pass data between fragments in ViewPager but trigger is on MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

so I want to pass data from one to another. I'm using ViewPager to make fragments change when I click some trigger which is a button. What I want is when I click the `buttonLanjut` from MainActivity, I can set data from `MerchantTambahBarangFragment` and get that data to `MerchantTambahKategoriFragment`. I'm confused because the trigger is on `MainActivity` not in the fragment. Code below

**ParentActivity which is same as MainActivity**

```
class MerchantTambahParentActivty : AppCompatActivity(){
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMerchantTambahParentActivtyBinding
    var currentFragPosition = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMerchantTambahParentActivtyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //Toolbar
        setToolbar()

        //Tabpager
        val pagerAdapter = PagerAdapterTambahBaran(this, supportFragmentManager)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        nextOrBackPageAction()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, MerchantKelolaBarangActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun setToolbar() {
        supportActionBar?.apply {
            title = "Tambah Barang"
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun nextOrBackPageAction(){
       when (currentFragPosition) {
            0 -> {
                binding.buttonKembali.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
        binding.buttonLanjut.setOnClickListener {

            binding.buttonKembali.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            if(currentFragPosition <= 3){
                currentFragPosition++
                Toast.makeText(this, currentFragPosition.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if(currentFragPosition == 4){
                    binding.buttonLanjut.text = "SUBMIT"
                    binding.buttonLanjut.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)
                }
                binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentFragPosition, true)

            }
        }
        binding.buttonKembali.setOnClickListener {
            if(currentFragPosition > 0){
                currentFragPosition--
                if(currentFragPosition == 0){
                    binding.buttonKembali.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                binding.buttonLanjut.text = "Lanjut"
                binding.buttonLanjut.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, id.co.leholeh.R.drawable.ic_arrow_next, 0)
                binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentFragPosition, true)
            }
        }
    }
```

}

**MerchantTambahBarangFragment.kt**

class MerchantTambahBarangFragment : Fragment() {

```
lateinit var binding : FragmentMerchantTambahBarangBinding
private lateinit var cacheUtil: CacheUtil
private lateinit var auth: Login
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentMerchantTambahBarangBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    cacheUtil = CacheUtil()
    cacheUtil.start(requireActivity(), ConstantAuth.PREFERENCES)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.cacheUtil.get(ConstantAuth.AUTH))) {
        startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), LoginActivity::class.java))
    } else {
        auth = getAuth(cacheUtil)
        //setDataCategories()
        binding.inputCover.setOnClickListener {
            ImagePicker.create(this)
                .single()
                .start()
        }

    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        val image: Image = ImagePicker.getFirstImageOrNull(data)
        Glide.with(binding.imageViewCover).load(image.uri).into(binding.imageViewCover)
        binding.imageViewCover.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
}
```

**MerchantTambahKategoriFragment.kt**

```
class MerchantTambahKategoriFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var binding : FragmentTambahKategoriBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentTambahKategoriBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}


}
```

**PagerAdapterTambahBarang.kt**

```
class PagerAdapterTambahBaran(
    private val context: Context,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager ) : 
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

override fun getCount() = 5

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
    0 -> MerchantTambahBarangFragment()
    1 -> MerchantTambahKategoriFragment()
    2 -> MerchantTambahLokasiFragment()
    3 -> MerchantTambahFotoFragment()
    4 -> MerhchantSubmitBarangFragment()
    else-> Fragment()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a **SharedViewModel** between the activity and the fragments, where in the activity when you click on the button you can update some **LiveData** where the children fragments observe.
you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44655954/10138208) for more info about this approach