# How to send recyclerView data to another layout

Tags: android

When I select an item from recyclerView on the right side, I need to show that object's information on the left side. I was stuck at onClick in recyclerViewAdapter class. I created a fragment but I couldn't manage it. Here is the structure that I was trying to do: [image]

I need to put the selected item's information in this XML file and show it on the left side.

```
public class ProductRwAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductRwAdapter.ProductHolder> {

    ArrayList<Product> productArrayList;

    public ProductRwAdapter(ArrayList<Product> productArrayList) {
        this.productArrayList = productArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerRowBinding recyclerRowBinding = RecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),parent,false);

        return new ProductHolder(recyclerRowBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductRwAdapter.ProductHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.productName.setText(productArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.productAmount.setText(Integer.toString(productArrayList.get(position).getAmount()));
        Picasso.get().load(productArrayList.get(position).getImageUri()).into(holder.recyclerRowBinding.productImage);
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.textViewCardTotal.setText(Long.toString(productArrayList.get(position).getAmount() * productArrayList.get(position).getPrice()) + " TL ");

        
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.imageViewClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productArrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

        
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                Fragment myFragment = new fragmentInfo();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();



            }
        });
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.buttonIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               int productAmountInt = Integer.parseInt(holder.recyclerRowBinding.productAmount.getText().toString());
               productAmountInt++;
               String produtAmountString = Integer.toString(productAmountInt);
               productArrayList.get(position).setAmount(productAmountInt);
               holder.recyclerRowBinding.productAmount.setText(produtAmountString);
               holder.recyclerRowBinding.textViewCardTotal.setText(Long.toString(productArrayList.get(position).getAmount() * productArrayList.get(position).getPrice()) + " TL ");
            }
        });
        holder.recyclerRowBinding.buttonDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int productAmountInt = productArrayList.get(position).getAmount();

                //if amount of product is greater than 1 (2 or more) decrease it otherwise don't do anything
                if(productAmountInt > 1){
                    productAmountInt--;
                    String produtAmountString = Integer.toString(productAmountInt);
                    productArrayList.get(position).setAmount(productAmountInt);
                    holder.recyclerRowBinding.productAmount.setText(produtAmountString);
                    holder.recyclerRowBinding.textViewCardTotal.setText(Long.toString(productArrayList.get(position).getAmount() * productArrayList.get(position).getPrice()) + " TL ");

                }

            }
        });



    }

    public class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       private RecyclerRowBinding recyclerRowBinding;

        public ProductHolder(RecyclerRowBinding  recyclerRowBinding) {
            super(recyclerRowBinding.getRoot());

            this.recyclerRowBinding = recyclerRowBinding;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel to passing data between two fragments.
Create a Viewmodel and observe it in left side fragment,
when item selected set value in ViewModel and you can show informations of item selected.

[Sharing data between fragments using new architecture component ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272914/sharing-data-between-fragments-using-new-architecture-component-viewmodel)