# How do I manually call the ViewModel observer second time?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two `Fragment`-s with `RecyclerView` and `LiveData` both. When I made some changes in second fragment, I need to update `RecyclerView` in first fragment.
So after update second fragment I need to trigger `onChange` method in first fragment.
Code from first fragment:

```
item_viewmodel.getAllCategoryModel().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Items>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Items> myLists) {
       //Observer is already registered, but I need to call it manully from second fragment.
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Shared viewmodel, create a instance of viewmodel in both the fragments and use accordingly, for more details visit this page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272914/sharing-data-between-fragments-using-new-architecture-component-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

You should try use Transformations.switchMap() method, put that the first livedata depends of the second livedata by the method describe above

Here is an example class that holds a typed-in name of a user String (such as from an EditText) in a MutableLiveData and returns a LiveData containing a List of User objects for users that have that name. It populates that LiveData by requerying a repository-pattern object each time the typed name changes.

This ViewModel would permit the observing UI to update "live" as the user ID text changes.

```
 class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
 MutableLiveData<String> nameQueryLiveData = ...

 LiveData<List<String>> getUsersWithNameLiveData() {
     return Transformations.switchMap(
         nameQueryLiveData,
             name -> myDataSource.getUsersWithNameLiveData(name));
 }

 void setNameQuery(String name) {
     this.nameQueryLiveData.setValue(name);
 }
}
```

[Here more about this...](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations)

If you want more specific answer please post all code about your viewModel

Answer (score 0):

I assume best way would be to use `by activityViewModels()` kotlin property delegate in fragments and share the host activity's `Viewmodel` for cross fragment communication.

More about usage [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

Comment: Well, I tried things like in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/ACK67xU1Y3s but only one onChange method in single fragment is trigger. I observe same item as it is in this video and when I am in frag A change something only onChange method in frag A is trigger. Analogy it is with frag B. Is that what you meant with the SharedViewModel on this video?