# How can I store and update a common (temporary) data between activities and fragments in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, sharedpreferences, viewmodel

i have an application with multiple fragments and activities. I'm wondering if I can create a container class between fragments. (I want to save with set and pull with get)

For example, I will save the gender information of the user in the FragmentA class, and then I will use this information when I switch to FragmentB. In the same way; I will get the user's age, height, weight in FragmentC class. and then I will access this information in the FragmentE (Final) class and save it to the Room database. How can I do this? Could you please give an example in Java?

Note: I'm using Shared Preferencens but I want to look for a different method as I don't know if it works asynchronously or synchronously. For example, can we create such a container with ViewModel LiveData, store the data and access it from anywhere?

Comment: You can also consider a class with static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared ViewModel in Android to communicate with other fragments. You can save your all data in this SharedViewModel and acsess it in all the fragments.

Please follow this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-viewmodel-in-android/

Here they have used two fragment which act as sender and  receiver similarly you can create for your multiple fragments

//Java Implementation of  SharedViewModel

[Sharing data between fragments using new architecture component ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272914/sharing-data-between-fragments-using-new-architecture-component-viewmodel)

Comment: Can you share an example for java?

Comment: Java example of SharedViewModel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272914/sharing-data-between-fragments-using-new-architecture-component-viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask another question? Do you think it makes sense to use shared prefrences or sharedviewmodel?

Comment: If  you want to keep your data saved even  if user kills the app then use SharedPrefrences otherwise sharedViewModel

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/sharedviewmodel-in-kotlin-ec9b09b41a78